# play sound on different outputs, based on what display its the "player" is displayed on?

Tags: 14.04, display, screen, tv, output

Is there any way to play sound on different outputs, based on what display its the "player" is displayed on?

E.x if its played on the computer screen it uses analog output, but if its displayed on the hdmi tv, it uses the digital output

ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup Multiseats(https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg_multiseat)
i got it semi working, know that its possible, what you need is 2 pulseaudio daemons.
Im sure you could do this with other soundmanagers than pulseaudio.

Comment: I am sure you can provide a better answer - write complete sentences, explain what needs to be done.